# Usando Selenium como selecionar dois elementos diferentes que possuem o mesmo ID?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Minha tentativa com o xPath ou pelo ID foi mal sucedida.

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");

        var chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        chromeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://radar.tntbrasil.com.br/radar/public/login");

        chromeDriver.FindElementById("login").SendKeys("");
        chromeDriver.FindElementById("senha").SendKeys("");

        chromeDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"login\"]/a")).Click();
        chromeDriver.FindElementById("login").SendKeys(Keys.Enter);

        chromeDriver.Close();
```

Segue as imagens para facilitar o entendimento:

[image: Imagem do site onde mostra que a caixa de texto para informar o login e o botão acessar possuem o mesmo id]

[image: Código fonte onde busco o botão Login]

Comment: Bom.. primeiro os dois elementos não deveriam ter o mesmo ID... mas você pode tentar diferenciar pelo type

Comment: Você sabe me dizer como fazer isso? Por que esqueci de informar mas minha tentativa pelo xPath não foi bem sucedida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma vez que os elementos possuem o mesmo `id`, embora isso esteja errado, ao invés do seu `XPath` fazer uma query por todos os elementos que possuem o id=login, `//*[@id="login"]`, você pode identificar qual tipo de elemento com esse id você está procurando.

```
//Para o input do login
chromeDriver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//input[@id=\"login\"]")).SendKeys("");

//Para o click no botão
chromeDriver.FindeElement(By.XPath("//a[@id=\"login\"]")).Click();
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.